# Best way to display a datepicker?

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker

I have a view in which you can edit your profile.
I'm trying to think of the best way to display a datepicker as having it on the view on it's own is too big.

I was considering of using an alert controller to display it in an action sheet but then I read that Apple discourages this.

Possibly an overlay?

Anyone have any other ideas, they would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can have it hidden until needed. So you could display the date on a button, or in a tableView cell, then when tapped just set it's hidden flag to FALSE. You'd need to move things around to accommodate when it appears, and move them back once the date was selected.